# Select option robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Really quick (but complicated?) question.

I have this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_products" class="selectmultiple" name="products">
    <option value="3243">testproductP (3243)</option>
    <option value="3244">testproductQ (3244)</option>
</select>
```

I need to robotframework with selenium to replicate that I select an option. However I can not find a keyword like "Select Option". So I tried using "Click Element" with an xpath pointing to the option.

```
Click Element  xpath=//select[@name="products"]/option[@value=3244]
```

However this fails the test with the error: "timeout: timed out"

The xpath returns the correct element, but somehow it times out. Maybe Click Element is not supposed to be used like this, but I can't find a better keyword.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click Element waits for a page load event unless you give it an additional parameter telling it not to wait. However, you should also be able to use the "Select From List" keyword.

Have fun!

Comment: Here's an example:
  `Select From List  xpath=//select[@name="products"]  3244`
(double spaces seem to get eliminated by stack overflow)

Comment: Select From List appears to work, However now I am getting the same error when I need to click on a <span> element. I've tried using the don't wait argument but that didnt seem to help here, i should probably create a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
   Select From List  ${XPATH}    Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use " select element by value " keyword and specify the Xpath of the list dropdown and value of component which you want to select from list.

Answer (score 0):

Select From List By Value      **Xpath=""/ID=""/Name=""**      Value

Comment: USE Tab space before and after the bold content visible

Answer (score -2):

Try to select the element using Javascript. Example:

Execute Javascript   `document.querySelector("your css").click()`